# Set margin for each page?

Tags: margins

I know using `\newgeometry{left=xcm,bottom=xcm}` and `\restoregeometry` can help to set a new margin, but I don't know where I should put this to reset only the second page (or third, etc.). Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{First section} \lipsum[1-4]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[5-8]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[9-12]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[13-14]
\end{document}
```

My question is: how to set different margins for different pages? i.e.,

for the 1st page:  `\geometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in};`

for the 2nd page:  `\geometry{top=2in,bottom=2in,left=2in,right=2in};`

for the 3rd page:  `\geometry{top=3in,bottom=3in,left=3in,right=3in};`

[image]

Comment: Do you only have a different *first* page? Or do you have random page margin alterations throughout your document?

Comment: @Werner sorry, I am not very sure about your question. I want to be able to set different margins for different pages.

Comment: @FzLbMj: If you document has a single odd-margined page, it's possible to manually make changes fairly easily. However, for multiple odd-margined pages, you'll have to suggest a manual change around every page break.

Comment: @Werner yeah, the later is what I want to do. However, when you write a document, it is not possible to exactly define where is the start of a new page since the content may be changed.

Comment: Ok, i have to ask. Why do you want to have different margins for every page?

Comment: @Johannes_B This is because the publication template I use require the first and the rest page has different margins. I know this requirement can be fulfilled by using the largest margin for every page, but it looks not that good. So, I want to know where I should put the geometry command for the second page.

Comment: is your first page a title page with just the title? No content?

Comment: @Johannes_B no, there is content.

Comment: The package 'afterpage' allows to execute some code at the beginning of the next page.

Comment: thanks. I think this may be a way to solve it. I will give a try.